# Rails Controller Inheritance vs. Concerns and Mixins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a lot of similar resources in my Rails application, and I have currently DRY'd up the code using controller inheritance. I see that there is a directory called concerns under the controller folder, where I could potentially write similar concerns (such as archiving, activate/deactivate etc.) I can probably write mixins too.

Is there a preferred approach to DRY up the controller code? Is there any downside in using inheritance, or are there any advantages using other techniques?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a preferred approach to DRY up the controller code?

In my experience, it depends on what you want the code to do. I've only used concerns for simple controller-independent methods, such as `before_action` or something

I would use inheritance if your controller's methods are able to rely on a [super class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html) or something. My experience so far has lead me to use [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) - a DRY way to create controller inheritance